# C++ to .NET Csharp swig DoubleVector.ToArray()

Tags: c++, vb.net, swig, enumeration, toarray

I have an object named result, which contains a IntegerVector and a DoubleVector in C++.
I generate with a Task(Of Results) n diferent results and have them in gotresults as Taks from result, that is in C++.

When I use gotresults(j).IntegerVector.ToArray() I have no problems, but using the gotresults(j).DoubleVector.ToArray() I get an index error.

When im debbuging I see the DoubleVector has information using gotresults(j).DoubleVector.count, but after the error shows it says the count is 0 and in Results View "Enumeration yielded no results".

¿Could anyone help me to get the DoubleVector from C++ correctly to an object in VB.NET?

Simple code below (I have TASKS = 1 now, but it still doesnt work):

1. In C++:

   ```
    struct ResultCPP {

        std::vector<double> doubleseriecpp
        std::vector<int> intseriecpp

    }

    Necesaries to calculate a doubel series and int series to get the ResultCPP object in C++.
   ```
2. functionAsync(param) and ResultContainer:

   ```
    Friend Class ResultContainer

         Public doubleserie As Swig4CSharp.DoubleVector
         Public integerserie As Swig4CSharp.IntVector

    End Class

    Private Async Function funcionAsync(params) As Task(Of ResultContainer)

        Return Await Task.Run(Function()

            Dim result as New ResultContainer

            Dim resultaux As New CCode.ResultCPP

            resultaux = CodeCPP.calculate(params)

            result.doubleserie = resultaux.doubleseriecpp
            result.intserie = resultaux.interiecpp

            Return result

        End Function)

    End Function
   ```
3. VB.NET.

   ```
    Const TASKS As Integer = 1

    For i As Integer = 0 to n Step TASKS

        Dim correlation task As New List(Of Task(Of ResultContainer))

        For j As Integer = 0 to TASKS -1
            function_task.Add(functionAsync(param))
        Next

        Task.WaitAll(correlation_task.ToArray)

        For j As Integer = 0 To TASKS - 1

        Dim corrdates() As Integer
        Dim corrseries() As Double

        If correlation_task(j).Result.corr_serie Is Nothing or 
            correlation_task(j).Result.corr_date Is Nothing Then

            ReDim corrdates(0)
            corrdates(0) = Integer.MinValue

            ReDim corrseries(0)
            corrseries(0) = Double.MinValue

        Else

           corrdates_temp1 = 
           correlation_task(j).Result.intseries.ToArray()
           Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

           corrseries_temp = 
           correlation_task(j).Result.doubleseries.ToArray()
           Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        End If

    Next
   ```

   Next

And with few series (a small n) I get no problem, but if the n is bigger, then I get a problem in doubleseries.ToArray() and if I debbug I see it starts to generate te array in VB.NET, but then at some point failes to keep building it. Its usually with doubleseries, not so usual with intseries.

Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: Can you provide code for a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: I added the basic building blocks in C++ and VB.NET, thank you.